# How do I check if a line in a CSV file is not the header row, and then append each line of the file to a variable, excluding the header?

Tags: python, csv, append, readlines

I need to use an "if" statement to check if a line in a CSV file is not the header row. Then, I need to append each line of the CSV file to a variable called "mailing_list," excluding the header. How should I do this? This is the CSV file and what I have so far (may not be correct).

```
uuid,username,email,subscribe_status
307919e9-d6f0-4ecf-9bef-c1320db8941a,afarrimond0,thartus0@reuters.com,opt-out
8743d75d-c62a-4bae-8990-3390fefbe5c7,tdelicate1,skinmond1@ca.gov,opt-out
68a32cae-847a-47c5-a77c-0d14ccf11e70,edelahuntyk,fglossup2@gmail.com,OPT-OUT
a50bd76f-bc4d-4141-9b5d-3bfb9cb4c65d,tdelicate10,hpatel3@springer.com,active
26edd0b3-0040-4ba9-8c19-9b69d565df36,ogelder2,bissett4@mozilla.org,unsubscribed
5c96189f-95fe-4638-9753-081a6e1a82e8,bnornable3,aerrett5@over-blog.com,opt-out
480fb04a-d7cd-47c5-8079-b580cb14b4d9,csheraton4,pgatherell6@1.com,active
d08649ee-62ae-4d1a-b578-fdde309bb721,tstodart5,schasmoor7@gmail.com,active
5772c293-c2a9-41ff-a8d3-6c666fc19d9a,mbaudino6,hpatel3@springer.com,unsubscribed
9e8fb253-d80d-47b5-8e1d-9a89b5bcc41b,paspling7,dandersen9@mozilla.org,active
055dff79-7d09-4194-95f2-48dd586b8bd7,mknapton8,vlewndenh@spiegel.de,active
5216dc65-05bb-4aba-a516-3c1317091471,ajelf9,kmacpaikei@purevolume.com,unsubscribed
41c30786-aa84-4d60-9879-0c53f8fad970,cgoodleyh,ccowlinj@hp.com,active
3fd55224-dbff-4c89-baec-629a3442d8f7,smcgonnelli,dcarragherk@gmail.com,opt-out
2ac17a63-a64b-42fc-8780-02c5549f23a7,mmayoralj,bparsissonl@domainmarket.com,unsubscribed
```

```
import csv

base_url = '../dataset/'


def read_mailing_list_file():
    with open('mailing_list.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        line_count = 0

        mailing_list = open("mailing_list.csv").readlines()
        for row in file_reader:
```

I am not sure what to try, but I am expecting to append each line of the CSV file to the mailing_list variable, excluding the header.

Comment: Do your CSV files always have headers? If yes, you can always skip the first line by putting `header = next(file_reader)` before your for-loop.

Comment: It is odd that you are opening your file twice. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Sniffer` class from [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

From docs:

> has_header(sample)

> Analyze the sample text (presumed to be in CSV format) and return True if the first row appears to be a series of column headers. Inspecting each column, one of two key criteria will be considered to estimate if the sample contains a header:

> ```
>        the second through n-th rows contain numeric values
> ```

> ```
>        the second through n-th rows contain strings where at >least one value’s length differs from that of the putative header of that column.
> ```

> Twenty rows after the first row are sampled; if more than half of columns + rows meet the criteria, True is returned.

> Note

> This method is a rough heuristic and may produce both false positives and negatives.

```
import csv 

with open('mailing_list.csv') as csv_file:
    hdr = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csv_file.read())
    csv_file.seek(0)
    r = csv.reader(csv_file)
    mailing_list = []
    if hdr:
        next(r)
    for row in r:
        mailing_list.append(row)

mailing_list                                                                                                                                                              
Out[11]: 
[['307919e9-d6f0-4ecf-9bef-c1320db8941a',
  'afarrimond0',
  'thartus0@reuters.com',
  'opt-out'],
 ['8743d75d-c62a-4bae-8990-3390fefbe5c7',
  'tdelicate1',
  'skinmond1@ca.gov',
  'opt-out'],
 ['68a32cae-847a-47c5-a77c-0d14ccf11e70',
  'edelahuntyk',
  'fglossup2@gmail.com',
  'OPT-OUT'],
 ['a50bd76f-bc4d-4141-9b5d-3bfb9cb4c65d',
  'tdelicate10',
  'hpatel3@springer.com',
  'active'],

  ...

 ['3fd55224-dbff-4c89-baec-629a3442d8f7',
  'smcgonnelli',
  'dcarragherk@gmail.com',
  'opt-out'],
 ['2ac17a63-a64b-42fc-8780-02c5549f23a7',
  'mmayoralj',
  'bparsissonl@domainmarket.com',
  'unsubscribed'],
 []]
```